# Out of scope static methods

Tags: java, methods

So in a CodeHS class I'm taking I'm trying to separate the cents from a balance of a bank account. Ex turn 12.34 to 34. I'm trying to use value.indexOf() and value.length() where value the balance. However, I keep getting "You may have forgotten to declare length() or it's out of scope" errors. I'm so confused because I thought these were built into Java itself but maybe not? I've already looked through the documentation but I'm still lost. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code of the method (I think its a method idk the vocab lmao)

```java
public class Currency
{
    private Double value;
    
    // Constructor
    public Currency(Double startValue)
    {
        value = startValue;
    }
    
    // Sets value to newValue
    public void setValue(Double newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }
    
    // Returns the dollar portion of value
    // if value is 12.34, returns 12
    public Integer getDollars()
    {
        return (int)value.doubleValue();
    }
    
    // Returns the cents portion of value
    // as an Integer
    // if value is 12.34, returns 34
    public Integer getCents()
    {
        return value.subSequence(value.indexOf("."), value.length());
    }
    
    // Returns a String representation
    // in the format
    // $12.34
    public String toString()
    {
        return value.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: The field `value` is of type `Double`. That type doesn't have `indexOf()` and `length()` methods. It seems like you're trying to treat it as a string - it's not...

Comment: (And I don't know which `subSequence` method you expect to call that would return an `Integer`, either...)

Comment: I just started on the lesson on Integer, Double, Character value types and I'm pretty confused. How can I convert double to String? I'm trying casting but it's not working.

Comment: "I just started on the lesson on Integer, Double, Character" If you're just learning Java, then using a String to extract the cents portion is probably NOT the "correct way". *Plus, looking for a `.` is problematic in other countries that don't use period as a decimal separator. You're probably supposed to multiply the money value by 1,000 to get the total number of pennies and store that in an int. Then cast the original money value to an int to get just the dollar portion. Multiply that by 100 and subtract that number from the total number of pennies to get just the number of pennies.

Comment: @user85421 Yeah, I'm brain dead at the moment. Should be 100 not 1,000. And you're right, Java always uses `.`. I'm thinking of C#, which uses the current locale. Too many languages in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Commented by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77368364/out-of-scope-static-methods#comment136395025_77368364), you are treating a `Double` as if it is text. It is not text.

If you want text, make a `String` object. Call [`Double#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString()). This method generates text to represent the value of the number held within the `Double` object. The `Double` object contains no text.

```
String s = myDouble.toString() ;
```

For a `double` primitive, use the `static` method [`Double.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)).

```
double x = 42.7d ;
String s = Double.toString( x ) ;
```

`String` offers the `indexOf` and `length` methods you seek.

---

By the way, in real work we never use `double`/`Double` types for money matters. Those floating-point types [trade away accuracy for speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) of execution.

For money matters, when accuracy is crucial, use the [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class. Or, alternatively, multiply to get whole numbers as mentioned in [another Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77368364/out-of-scope-static-methods/77368445#comment136395569_77368364).

Comment: Oohh I was wondering what toString did okay I get it now thank you!

Comment: I would prefer to use just ``double`` but the lesson is trying to teach me all the array data types so I'll just suffer through it =p